# AttributeError: 'Resume' object has no attribute 'prefetch_related'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to understand the use of prefetch_related and select_related for optimization. I learned somewhere in the blog that one of the where to use prefetch and select is, prefetch_related is used for reverse relation and select_related for the forward relation. In my case there is Resume model and Education Model. Education model has FK of resume with the related_name for reverse relation instead of writing additional _set when querying. I need to list all the education of an requested user with the requested user resume. I could do this without those optimization techniques as follow

```
education_instance = Resume.objects.get(applicant=request.user).educations.all()
```

When I tried to use the following instead, I get the error I stated in the title

```
education_instance = Resume.objects.filter(applicant=request.user).prefetch_related('educations')
```

Here is my model

```
class Resume(models.Model):
    applicant = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, help_text="Full Name")

class Education(models.Model):
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, related_name='educations')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, help_text="Name of an institution")
```

Can anyone make me clear on select_related and prefetch_related with simple layman terms ? I could not understand the issue I am getting

Answer (score 4):

From the Exception that you provided, you are trying to call `.prefetch_related()` on object `Resume`, not `Resume`s `QuerySet`.

So, make sure you run

```
Resume.objects.filter(applicant=request.user).prefetch_related('educations')
```

not

```
Resume.objects.get(applicant=request.user).prefetch_related('educations')
```

Comment: That way i get only one queryest instead of all

Comment: @milan what do you mean by one `QuerySet`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should use select_related in this case.
As far as i know prefetch_related is used for many to many relations and it makes two queries to retrieve objects while select_related is used for normal fk or one to one relations and it fetched all objects in one query using joins.

Answer (score 0):

first of all go through this [document of prefetch_related][1]

[1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related then you will find that you can not use it like this

you have to apply on Education modal

```
education_instance = Education.objects.filter(resume__applicant == request.user).prefetch_related('resume')
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will sure look at all the link you all have referred for me. Before going to that link, I am not sure I will get into it or not so I want to ask what is that resume inside prefetch_related. Is it the field(fk) in Education table?

Comment: yes resume in prefetch_related is fk in Education table.